# Pandas groupby, aggregate, and merge throwing ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

Given this dataset:

```
id     timestamp     lng     lat
V1        123        100     30
V1        124        100     31
V1        125        101     29
V2        126        102     30
V2        127        105     31
```

I want to group by "id" and get the first and last "timestamp" and call them "start_time" and "stop_time". I want the "lng" and "lat" associated with the first and last "timestamp" in each group. Finally, I want all the lng and lat associated with a group as a list or dictionary (with timestamp as key). So, the result might look like:

```
   start_time stop_time     start_lng     start_lat    end_lng     end_lat    path_lng     path_lat     
V1     123      125            100            30          101        29     [100,100,101] [30,31,29]
V2     126      127            102            30          105        31     [102,105]     [30,31]
```

I can get the "start_time" and "stop_time". I thought the best way to get the "lng" and "lat" of each would be to merge with the original dataframe twice. But, I keep getting "ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat" and cannot figure out which columns it is referring to. For the last step, I thought applying a lambda function build a dictionary or list might work, but I have not gotten that far yet. Here is my code:

```
col0 = ["V1","V1","V1","V2","V2"]
col1 = [123,124,125,126,127]
col2 = [100,100,101,102,105]
col3 = [30,31,29,30,31]
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":col1,"fixed_lng":col2,"fixed_lat":col3},index=[col0])
df.index.name = "id"

summary = df.groupby(df.index.values).agg(
    start_timestamp=pd.NamedAgg(column='timestamp', aggfunc='min'),
    stop_timestamp=pd.NamedAgg(column='timestamp', aggfunc='max')
)

merged = summary.merge(df,left_index=True, right_index=True, left_on=["start_timestamp"], right_on=["timestamp"])
```

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Pandas 0.25.1 via Anaconda3 64bit on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use, if your timestamps in dataframe are ordered:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(start_timestamp=('timestamp', 'min'),
                        stop_timestamp=('timestamp', 'max'),
                        start_long=('fixed_lng', 'first'),
                        start_lat=('fixed_lat','first'),
                        end_long=('fixed_lng', 'last'),
                        end_lat=('fixed_lat', 'last'),
                        path_lng=('fixed_lng', list),
                        path_lat=('fixed_lat', list))
```

Output:

```
    start_timestamp  stop_timestamp  start_long  start_lat  end_long  end_lat         path_lng      path_lat
V1              123             125         100         30       101       29  [100, 100, 101]  [30, 31, 29]
V2              126             127         102         30       105       31       [102, 105]      [30, 31
```

Where your input df is:

```
col0 = ["V1","V1","V1","V2","V2"]
col1 = [123,124,125,126,127]
col2 = [100,100,101,102,105]
col3 = [30,31,29,30,31]
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":col1,"fixed_lng":col2,"fixed_lat":col3},index=col0)
df.index.name = "id"
```

Comment: Simply sorting by timestamp eliminated the need for the joins. I didn't realize "list" was an available aggregation function. That eliminates the need to use apply. This is not only a solution, it is a direct and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make two grouped tables using .first() and .last(), and merge them by index (using .join() which is the special method for joining along the index), pretty straightforward stuff. 
If you struggle to implement this, I can make an example.